# If A is a skew-symmetric matrix with entries from R, and A is not the zero matrix, prove A is diagonalizable over C, but not R?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw this question before, but am not sure how to prove it. I know that if n is odd (nxn matrix), then 0 is an eigenvalue for A.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $A$ is real and skew-symmetric, then $B := iA$ is Hermitian. Let $B = Q\Lambda Q^*$ and orthogonal diagonalization of $B$. Then $A = Q (-i\Lambda)Q^*$. Note that $\Lambda$ is real, if $\Lambda \ne 0$ can $A$ be diagonizable over $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

1. Show that $A^T A$ can only have non-negative eigenvalues.
2. Check what happens to $A^T Ax$ if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, i.e. $Ax = \lambda x$.